# Should exceptions be used for form validation?

Tags: php, exception, validation

This might be a n00bish question, but whatever. Is okay to use exceptions for form validation? Let's say I have a form which asks users for their name and email, is right to do the following?

```
try {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        throw new UserRegistrationException("Your name cannot be empty.");
    }

    if (filter_var($_POST["email"])) {
        throw new UserRegistrationException("Invalid email");
    }

    // Save new user into database
} catch (UserRegistrationException $e) {
    // Show errors on screen
}
```

Also -if this is in fact the correct way to do it- if the user submits **both** an empty name and an invalid email, would both of the exceptions execute or only the one that appears first (the name one in this case)?

I'm using [PHP](http://www.php.net/) by the way.

Comment: It is definitely a strange way of using exceptions. "would both of the exceptions execute or only the one that appears first" -- is it that difficult to write 5 lines of code and see yourself?

Comment: Only the first would be thrown and caught, others skipped. If you need to accumulate error messages, you're better off just using a plain old if/else chain and appending messages onto an array.

Comment: @Michael I thought so... It seemed like a good occation to use exceptions though (as invalid input should be considered _exceptional_), but I'll stick to the if/else's

Comment: @John Doe: invalid input is **expected**. Exceptional is when no space left on HDD or when DBMS is down.

Comment: @zerkms What kind of criteria is that? No, invalid input is NOT expected, but it's so common that you have to be always prepared to catch it. No space left on HDD is less common, that's the only difference

Comment: @John Doe: invalid value is a normal flow, because you should never trust to the user's input. HDD space is not a normal flow, because your app cannot run if there is no sufficient space

Comment: @zerkms Then I think that exception catching should only be used as a last resort when things that one don't even expect to fail (unlike invalid input), fail. Right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally like to use exceptions for anything that should stop or alter program flow.  In other words, if validation of a particular field changes how data is processed, or requires the process to be repeated, then I always use exception for error handling.

If it's trivial, or I'm simply compiling a list of error messages, then I do not trigger exceptions.

To answer questions, two exceptions cannot be thrown at the same time.  The first throw statement that is reached will be thrown.  That's not to say that sometimes it doesn't make sense to rethrow as another type of exception.

Comment: I guess this is, as you say, a trivial case (and I'm also compiling a list of error messages) so exceptions wouldn't fit in this case

Comment: You could also extend the Exception class to append a stack of constructed exceptions, then throw an aggregated exception (which you could use to compile a list of error messages, loop through to find a particular one of interest, etc.)

Comment: Or you could build a collection of validation errors the old-fashioned way (e.g. appending to an array), and then throw a single validation exception containing all of those errors.

Comment: @AaronAdams You could do that, but I tend to think that an exception should have a single error associated with it so there is no confusion about what that exception means.  But I suppose it's a matter of preference.  Developers need to develop their own style as well.

Comment: @Nilpo I figure that from a programmatic perspective, "you submitted invalid data" is the exception. The specific invalidities (hey, look at me, just making up words) are just the "body" of the exception. Your controller will probably handle all validation errors identically; the only person interested in what those errors were is the user. It's especially nice because it lets the controller act as a "dumb" intermediary between the model and the user interface. But you're right, there's no one right answer! This is purely about style.

Answer (score 4):

The use case for exceptions is for *exceptional conditions*. In this case, do you expect the username and password fields to be blank? If you're displaying a web form, I'd argue that, yes, you do expect blank username and password fields, and so you should be checking for that condition explicitly, rather than throwing an exception.

To answer your specific question, both exceptions will not be thrown if an error is encountered. The throw statement will send the program into the catch block. From there control will flow as normal.

Comment: By your definition, every exception is unexpected.  How in the world would you know how to handle it then?  I would argue that exceptions are used for cases where the primary execution should not continue.

Comment: Not to mention one could simply add the validation errors to an array and then explode that to a string which is then thrown as an exception